# How to get back the old terminal tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: picture of good terminal]

My terminal tab was like this.

But now it look like this:

[image: bad terminal]

So I would like to have the last terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to open `settings.json` file, and looking for:

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
```

and make it `false`

And then your vscode terminal would have the old terminal tab.